# Some errors in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a code that generates errors on my PC but does't on other PC.I have windows 7 installed and also installed the compatible SDK for windows 7.I have also included the VC directories (from Tools -> option-> vc Diretories) but still the code generates follwing errors.

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'const unsigned int' when no variable is declared
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

statement generating error are as following

```
static const unsigned int MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR;
const unsigned int KeyLogger :: MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x02;
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code than that.
I would guess that you have a macro defined somewhere

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR and hitting F12 to see if the symbol is declared elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion !!! 
My problem solved by trying out your suggestion.

Comment: If it solved your problem, then why aren't you accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay actually I was not able to figer out how to accept the answer and thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What's `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR`? I ask because the error might indicate that this is some macro.

Why do you make a plain identifier (not a macro) all caps, anyway? That's just begging for one of the thousands of macros in `<windows.h>` to trample over it. (Not that not making it all caps would prevent that, since `<windows.h>` sacrilegiously defines many mixed-case macros...)

Otherwise you would have to paste some minimal, compilable example showing the problem.